# Lambda function with if statement [True or False output]

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, data-science, list-comprehension

Could you please help me to resolve this tackle?
Please find attached simple DF with 2 columns.

[image]

The goal of this check:
if month is equal June or July then check if working_time_in_hours is greater than 40
else check if working_time_in_hours is greater than 24.

Maybe sth like that however it does not work :(:

```
df["over_treshold"] = df.apply(lambda l: l.working_time_in_hours >= 40 if df.month == "June" | df.month =="July"  else l.working_time_in_hours >= 24)
```

The output should include a bool value in new column ["over_treshold]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and instead multiple `|` is used [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
 df["over_treshold"] = np.where(df.month.isin(["June", "July"]), 
                                df.working_time_in_hours >= 40 , 
                                df.working_time_in_hours >= 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
df["over_treshold"] = df.apply(lambda l: l.working_time_in_hours >= 40 if df.month == "June" | df.month =="July"  else l.working_time_in_hours >= 24, axis=1)
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
> Axis along which the function is applied:
>
> - 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
> - 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.